# C++ Project: converting a interger into a double

Tags: c++, integer, double, implicit-conversion

Hi to all I am new to programming with C++, and I have been assigned a project where I have to build a program that calculates the average birthrate & death rate percentage of a population. I am currently stuck on this step where I need to convert an integer value into a double value to get the correct output. For example, a function for finding the birthrate would be (births/population) and since dividing integers it causes the floating point number to be truncated giving me a result of 0 instead of getting (10/100 which would equal 0.1). I understand that I have declared integers, but that is the requirement. I have thought about typecasting but had no luck converting the value. I apologize for the long explanation I hope it makes sense. Thank you in advance!

**This is the following criteria:**

1. ***private variables***: have to be integers (population, births, deaths)
2. ***public functions***:

- **default constructor** with no parameters, initialize (population = 2), (births & deaths = 0)
- **constructor** with three parameters. The constructor should pass the population, the number of births, and deaths for the Population object.

3. **"Set" member function** for each of the three-member variables. If a population figure is less than 2 and is passed to the class, use a default value of 2. If a birth or a death figure less than 0 is passed, use a default value of 0.
4. **getBirthrate** member function. calculates the birth rate based on the following formula: (Birthrate = Number of births/population)
5. **getDeathrate** member function. calculates the death rate based on the following formula: (Deathrate = Number of deaths/ population)

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <iomanip>
   using namespace std;


   //  Population class declaration
   class Population
   {
   private:
       int population, births, deaths;

   public:
       // default constructor: with no parameters
       Population()
       {
           population = 2;
           births = 0;
           deaths = 0;
       }

       // constructor
       Population(int p, int b, int d)
       {
           population = p;
           births = b;
           deaths = d;
       }

       // birthrate member function
       int getBirthrate();
       // deathrate member function
       int getDeathrate();

       void setPopulation(int);
       void setBirth(int);
       void setDeath(int);
       int getPopulation();
       int getBirth(int);
       int getDeaths(int);
   };

   // member functions
   void Population::setPopulation(int p)
   {
       if (population < 2)
       {
           population = 2;
           cout << "Error: Invalid population input!" << endl;
       }
       else
       {
           population = p;
       }
   }

   void Population::setBirth(int b)
   {
       if (births < 0)
       {
           births = 0;
           cout << "Error: Invalid births input!" << endl;
       }
       else
       {
           births = b;
       }
   }

   void Population::setDeath(int d)
   {
       if (deaths < 0)
       {
           deaths = 0;
           cout << "Error: Invalid deaths input!" << endl;
       }
       else
       {
           deaths = d;
       }
   }

   int Population::getPopulation()
   {
       return population;
   }

   int Population::getBirth(int)
   {
       return births;
   }

   int Population::getDeaths(int)
   {
       return deaths;
   }

   // calculating functions
   int Population::getBirthrate()
   {
       return births / population;
   }

   int Population::getDeathrate()
   {
       return deaths / population;
   }

   // main function
   int main()
   {
       // instantiation of a population object
       Population x;

       int xBirths, xDeaths, xPopulation;

       // getting the values
       cout << "What is the population: " << endl;
       cin >> xPopulation;

       cout << "What is the number of births: " << endl;
       cin >> xBirths;

       cout << "What are the number of deaths: " << endl;
       cin >> xDeaths;

       // set functions
       x.setPopulation(xPopulation);
       x.setBirth(xBirths);
       x.setDeath(xDeaths);

       // calculating the values
       cout << "The population is: " << x.getPopulation() << endl;
       cout << "The birthrate is: " << x.getBirthrate() << endl;
       cout << "The deathrate is: " << x.getDeathrate() << endl;

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: *' I have thought about typecasting but had no luck converting the value'* When you have a problem with code you really must **show the code that doesn't work**. The way to do the conversion is `(double)val` where `val` is the value you want to convert. Now maybe you tried this, in which case your error was somewhere else, or maybe you didn't. There's no way to know and so no way to be sure of solving the actual problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that you have two problems

```
int Population::getDeathrate()
{
    return deaths / population;
}
```

The first is, as you've identified, you are doing integer division. You can solve that with a type cast. The second problem is that your function returns an integer, when it seems from the question above that you want a floating point result, e.g. 10/100 = 0.1. The solution to that problem is to change the return type to `double`.

So, putting both of those together

```
double Population::getDeathrate()
{
    return (double)deaths / (double)population;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, after switching the return type I was able to get the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
int Population::getBirthrate()
{
   return births / population;
}
```

do this:

```
int Population::getBirthrate()
{
   return (births * 1.0) / population;
}
```

multiplying an integer with 1.0 convert them into double.

Comment: Or you can just cast them to `double`.